# Android Custom Adapter not show all items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a custom adapter passing a List with 6 items to this adapter,

but only 3 items are being displayed in Samsung galaxy s6 and all items showing on galaxy j7 phone!

adapter `onBindViewHolder` code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    try {
        Toast.makeText( context, "items: " + items.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        News newsList = items.get( position );
        Picasso.with( context ).load( newsList.getThumbnail() ).into( holder.image );

        holder.txtNewsTitle.setText( newsList.getPublisherId() );
        holder.txtNewsType.setText( newsList.getTypeCode() );
        holder.txtTitle.setText( newsList.getTitle() );
        holder.txtDate.setText( newsList.getCreatedAt() );
        holder.txtLikeNumber.setText( newsList.getLikeCount() );
        //holder.txtComment.setText(newsList.getTxtComment());
        holder.txtSeen.setText( newsList.getViewCount() );

        Toast.makeText( context, "item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        holder.cardViewNewsList.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = ( (Activity) context ).getFragmentManager();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace( R.id.fragmentContainer, new ShowNewsFragment() ).addToBackStack( null ).commit();
            }
        } );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i( "onBindViewHolder", "onBindViewHolder: " + e );
    }

}
```

main layout:

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerNewsList"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

card view layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/xxsmall"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_linear_frag_search"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewNewsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/zero">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/xxxsmall">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xxsmall"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgShare"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_xsmall"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_xsmall"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_comment_client"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xlarg"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgAddBookmark"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_xsmall"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_xsmall"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite_client"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/medium"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtNewsTitle"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/xxxxlarg"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/medium"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/xxxsmall"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/xxxsmall"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small"
                        android:background="@drawable/frag_showlist_bg_btn_fars"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_xsmall" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/xxxxsmall"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/xxsmall"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xxsmall"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/xxsmall"
                android:background="@color/colorGray" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtNewsType"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingRight="@dimen/xxsmall"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/xxsmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGray"
                            android:lines="2"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_xsmall" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingRight="@dimen/xxsmall"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/xxsmall"
                            android:lines="2"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_xsmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_xbig"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_big"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/xxsmall"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/xxsmall"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/xxsmall"
                        app:cardElevation="0dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/image"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/xxxxsmall"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xxsmall"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/xxsmall"
                    android:background="@color/colorGray" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/xxxsmall"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/xxxsmall">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xxsmall"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorGrayText"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_xsmall" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xsmall"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgLike"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_xsmall"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_xsmall"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_like_client"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtLikeNumber"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xxxsmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorGrayText"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_xsmall"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xxsmall"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgComment"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_xsmall"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_xsmall"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_comment_client"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/commentNumber"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xxxsmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorGrayText"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_xsmall" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xxsmall"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgSeen"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_xsmall"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_xsmall"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_view_client" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtSeen"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xxxsmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorGrayText"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_xsmall" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Obtained Toasts outputs:

Toast 1 : items: 6

Toast 2 : item: 0

Toast 3 : item: 1

Toast 4 : item: 2

Comment: why are you not using recyclerview @mohammad?

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta i use recyclerview

Comment: Yeah my bad sorry i didn't see the above code.

Comment: use property called hasstableids

Comment: @rajkavadia what? :)

Comment: @mohammad In recyclerview ,Implement mathod called hasstable ids and make it true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **position** in the onBindViewHolder you have to use

```
holder.getAdapterPosition()
```

while fetching data from a list. The position that you are using in `onBindViewHolder` is the position of the item on the screen which will be limited to maximum number of items on your current screen.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    try {
        Toast.makeText( context, "items: " + items.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        News newsList = items.get( holder.getAdapterPosition() );
        Picasso.with( context ).load( newsList.getThumbnail() ).into( holder.image );

        holder.txtNewsTitle.setText( newsList.getPublisherId() );
        holder.txtNewsType.setText( newsList.getTypeCode() );
        holder.txtTitle.setText( newsList.getTitle() );
        holder.txtDate.setText( newsList.getCreatedAt() );
        holder.txtLikeNumber.setText( newsList.getLikeCount() );
        //holder.txtComment.setText(newsList.getTxtComment());
        holder.txtSeen.setText( newsList.getViewCount() );

        Toast.makeText( context, "item: " + holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        holder.cardViewNewsList.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = ( (Activity) context ).getFragmentManager();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace( R.id.fragmentContainer, new ShowNewsFragment() ).addToBackStack( null ).commit();
            }
        } );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i( "onBindViewHolder", "onBindViewHolder: " + e );
    }
}
```

**Update**

Use **NestedScrollView** instead of **ScrollView** and add `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

to your RecyclerView and use `android:fillViewport="true"` for your nestedScrollView too.

Comment: @mohammad add your layout to question.

Comment: @mohammad can you see other items if you scroll your list?

Comment: @mohammad are you check your list size before pass it to adapter?

Comment: yeah, items.size() is 6

Comment: @mohammad do you have scrollView or nestedScrollView inside your layout?

Comment: this problem is not related to layout, in onBindViewHolder i Toast position of item, only 0,1,2 Toasted for me.

Comment: I want to know that you are using scrollView or not.

Comment: @mohammad my answer was update. please check again that.

Comment: @mohammad your welcome bro. please give me upvote if my answer is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: sethasstableids]

the image shown the property for recyclerviewadapter sethasstableids .
make it reture true.